# Velocity.js 'toString' of undefined error in animation complete callback

Tags: jquery, animation, undefined, tostring, velocity.js

I just started implimenting velocity.js into my project for animations and I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

I'm getting the error on this line:

```
$newCart.velocity('slideDown', {duration: 750 });
```

My full code is:

```
var $cart           = $('div[data-role="wholeShoppingCartPanel"]')
 var $parentRow     = $cart.parent();
 $cart.velocity('slideUp',{ 
    duration: 500,
    complete: function(){
        $cart.remove();
        $newCart = $(decodedJson['cartHTML']).hide();
        $parentRow.prepend($newCart);
        $newCart.velocity('slideDown', {duration: 750 });
    }
});
```

Both the slide up and slide down animations are successfull, I just don't like having errors in my console. Does anyone have any idea on why I'm getting this error?

I would prefer to not 'band-aid' this error by using a try and catch considering such will cause additional overhead.

So I changed my code to:
`$cart.velocity('slideUp',{ 
    duration: 500,
    complete: function(){
        //$cart.remove();
        //$cart.hide();
        $newCart = $(decodedJson['cartHTML']).hide();
        //$parentRow.prepend($newCart);
        $cart.html(decodedJson['cartHTML']);
        //$newCart.velocity('slideDown', {duration: 750 });
        $cart.velocity('slideDown', {duration: 750 });
    }
});`

So instead of creating a new element I replace the current one's html. Can anyone tell me why this resolved the error?

Comment: When you go to the console and type $newCart = $(decodedJson['cartHTML']) what's the output of $newCart?? I think that cartHTML is an HTML string that never gets converted to a DOM element. I think you're missing a line that should be something like $('#SomeWrapper').html(decodedJson['cartHTML']);

Comment: Hmm, well instead of removing $cart, I could replace the html of it. But if I'm not mistaken by doing $parentRow.prepend($newCart); it should create the dom element, and obviously prepend the element. And like I said both the slideUp and slideDown animations are working thus concluding that the element does exists.

Comment: Please look at the original post to see my update.

Comment: Because the html was never a DOM element to begin with, it was just a string.

Comment: @frenchie How do I make it a dom via javascript/jquery? I thought the prepend created the dom element

Comment: You can use .html() or .prepend() or .append() like you did. The problem is that in the initial code you weren't using these.

Comment: My original code was using .prepend(). Line 8: `$parentRow.prepend($newCart);` My best guess is velocity doesn't work properly on dynamically added DOM elements. If the element was in the DOM on document ready it works fine but it appears any dynamic element causes that toString error. It still animates but for whatever reason throws that error.

Comment: what does this `decodedJson()` function do?

Comment: Where in your source does this error come from? jQuery? Velocity? Elsewhere? What is the line number?